# Bootstrap 4.5 scss compilation error on escapeSVG

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, sass, angular-cli

I've got an Angular 10 CLI project that I just updated to Bootstrap 4.5.

Now when I compile the app (we compile from Bootstrap's SCSS imported into our own to override variables) it fails with this error:

```
CssSyntaxError: /Users/st016lo/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_breadcrumb.scss:23:6: Can't resolve '/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSI5IiBoZWlnaHQ9IjE0Ij4KICAgIDxwYXRoIGZpbGw9InNpbHZlciIgZmlsbC1ydWxlPSJub256ZXJvIiBkPSJNNS41ODYgN0wuMjkzIDEuNzA3IDEuNzA3LjI5MyA4LjQxNCA3bC02LjcwNyA2LjcwNy0xLjQxNC0xLjQxNHoiLz4KPC9zdmc+Cg=' in '/Users/st016lo/github/ng-designsystem/client/src/sass/designsystem'

  21 |       padding-right: $breadcrumb-item-padding;
  22 |       color: $breadcrumb-divider-color;
> 23 |       content: escape-svg($breadcrumb-divider);
     |      ^
  24 |     }
  25 |   }
```

This did not happen with 4.3.1.  Any idea to fix other than editing the `/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss` to remove the import of `breadcrumb` (which allows it to compile)?

Answer (score 0):

I poked around and discovered we were overriding this variable with a `url()` containing a base64-encoded SVG, and now this variable expects an actual SVG, so I changed my override to

```
$breadcrumb-divider: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="9" height="14"> <path fill="silver" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M5.586 7L.293 1.707 1.707.293 8.414 7l-6.707 6.707-1.414-1.414z"/> </svg>');
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. We were also overriding the breadcrumb divider with a base64 encoded SVG, although I just had to put single quotes around the URL (previously we didn't have single quotes) rather than using an actual SVG.

```
$breadcrumb-divider: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSI4IiBoZWlnaHQ9IjgiPjxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0yLjUgMEwxIDEuNSAzLjUgNCAxIDYuNSAyLjUgOGw0LTQtNC00eiIgZmlsbD0iY3VycmVudENvbG9yIi8+PC9zdmc+');
```